# Qlikview : How create a Trigger on the last Date (Year)?

Tags: qlikview

I'm new on Qlikview and i'm a little bit stuck... I'm trying to build a trigger on my Document QV. It have to auto-select, when the document is launch, the Field [YearQ] and the last value (So 2014). [YearQ] inclued those values {2012, 2013, 2014}.

I've try

```
=Max[[AnnéeQ]] 
=Year(Today())=[AnnéeQ]
```

But that didn't work.

Could you help me pliz ?

Thx, in advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Put this into your on open trigger, for year based on reload date:

```
=Year(Today())
```

and this for the highest value in your year field:

```
=Max([AnnéeQ])
```

If you want the highest year based of a date do to this:

```
=Year(Max(DateField))
```